# Election using Arraylist Java

Tags: java

I'm completely new to Java. I have a project that requires me to use array lists to create an election. There are no pre-determined sets of candidates, whoever appears the most is the winner. The user needs to enter individual votes one vote per line (currently can have multiple votes) The program needs to finish executing when the user inputs -1.

I currently have the following:

```java
public class Voting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        ArrayList <Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            System.out.print("Choice of candidate: ");
            String lname=input.next();

            int total = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter vote: ");
            int votes=input.nextInt();
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school project I don't want to give the answer, but hopefully these are some tips that will help!

You want the loop to execute until a certain condition is true. Specifically, this condition is that the loop should execute until the user input is -1. Perhaps that should be in your loop condition then? I would recommend having a while loop that's condition is if user's input is != -1. If the user's input is not 1, then add the name that the user inputted into a list.

Now that you have the list of votes, you will need to do some processing to determine the votes/distinct name (probably in a loop that will go through all of the votes). Good luck!